# REST API to check if an object exists

Tags: rest, api

I have currently a webservice that load an object which looks like `/object/load?id=100`, the problem is that my object is really huge and it takes a long time to get the full response of the webservice just to see if the object exists or not.

What is the best pratice here ?

- Creating a new webservice `/object/exists?id=100` thats only use HTTP status code (200 if object exists, 404 if not) ?
- Add parameter to the `/object/load` webservice to return only simplified object ?

Comment: [HEAD](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.2) is probably what you are looking after

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are only interested in existence, or knowing in advance how the API will respond if you do a real `GET` request, HTTP actually has a built-in method for that: `HEAD`.

Comment: Did not know the comportement of HTTP HEAD method, but in my case, the HEAD request takes long time too... I guess this is generating the object on the server side that take long time here.

Comment: Yes, most web frameworks implement `HEAD` by doing a `GET` request and simply not sending the body. However, you should be able to override this behavior in whatever framework you're using. Simply don't generate the object when it's a `HEAD` request.

Answer (score -3):

I'd recommend creating a new method within your existing web service. Name that method 'Exists' or something similar, and make sure that it is a HttpGET method.

You could then pass in the ID of the object you want to check, then within the method just do a check to see if the object exists. If the object exists you should return true, else return false.

Comment: are you talking about the first solution I proposed ?

Comment: yeah, but instead if returning 200 or 404 (Which it will always return 200 if it can connect) i'd recommend just doing a quick check to see if the object exists, as you don't need to load the whole object; then just return a boolean value.